# Footnotes in a tabbing environment that breaks across pages

Tags: footnotes, tabbing

I am trying to use footnotes in a very long `tabbing` environment that breaks across two or more pages. I would like the footnote text to appear at the bottom of the page on which it occurs, however I have not found a way to do this. Using the `savenotes` environment around the `tabbing` environment, I can get all of the footnotes to appear at the bottom of the last page of the tabbing environment, but this is not desirable in my situation. It would be much clearer if the footnotes appeared at the bottom of the page they occur. Does anyone know of a work around?

**Edit:**
Here is my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage{footnote}
\begin{document}
paragraph before tabbing environment\footnote{testing footnote outside tabbing environment}
\begin{tabbing}
\quad\=\qquad\=\qquad\=\kill
\>1.\>i.\>first\footnote{testing footnote inside tabbing environment}\\
\>2.\>ii.\>second
\end{tabbing}
paragraph after tabbing environment
\end{document}
```

In this example, the footnote mark appears inside the `tabbing` environment, however the footnote text does not appear at the bottom of the page. The only way I could get the footnotes inside the `tabbing` environment to appear at the bottom of the page was to add a `savenotes` environment around the `tabbing` environment. See below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{footnote}
\begin{document}
paragraph before tabbing\footnote{testing footnote outside tabbing environment}
\begin{savenotes}
\begin{tabbing}
\quad\=\qquad\=\qquad\=\kill
\>1.\>i.\>first\footnote{testing footnote inside tabbing environment}\\
\>2.\>ii.\>second
\end{tabbing}
\end{savenotes}
paragraph after tabbing
\end{document}
```

This solves the problem of getting the footnotes that are inside the `tabbing` environment to display at the bottom of the page, however, for very long `tabbing` environments that break across more than one page, the footnotes do not appear until the final page on which the `savenotes` environment ends.

For my application, it is preferable to use the `tabbing` environment rather than a `table` or `tabular` because I need the tabbed list to be a part of the body of the text and to be able to break across pages.

Is there a way to have the footnotes appear at the bottom of the page they are on rather than on a different page after the `savenotes` environment ends? Having the footnotes on a different page may prove confusing for the readers of my report.

Comment: please add an example of your code to be more clear

Comment: I have posted an example below.

Comment: what about using `longtable` instead of `tabbing`?

Comment: `longtable` seems to have the same issue as `tabbing` in that the footnotes do not appear unless I also use `savenotes`, however in that case the footnotes are still only collected at the end rather than appearing on the page they occur. `longtable` and `tabbing` can both break across pages, whereas `tabular` cannot, so it makes sense for me to use either `longtable` or `tabbing`, but I still can't resolve the issue of getting the footnotes to appear on the pages they occur rather than all collected at the end.

Comment: with `longtable` footnote works well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, using `longtable` instead of `tabbing`

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
paragraph before longtable\footnote{testing footnote outside longtable environment}
\begin{longtable}[l]{lll}
1. & i. & first\footnote{testing footnote inside longtable environment}\\
2. &  ii. & second\\
3. & iii.& and more\footnote{testing footnote inside longtable environment}
\end{longtable}
paragraph after longtable
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution! The footnotes do indeed work inside a longtable that breaks across pages and they appear at the bottom of the page on which they occur.
Now the issue I have is that some of lines in my longtable will extend well beyond the end the line (past the page margin). I tried using parbox{} inside, but then the footnotes no longer work inside parbox{}. Also, how can I force the text inside parbox{} to wrap to the next line when it reaches the page margin?

Comment: @Luke you can try `\begin{longtable}[l]{llp{5cm}}` ...

Comment: Thanks @touhami, that certainly works. I am using 1inch margins with 8.5inch wide paper, so my text width is 6.5inch (or 469.755pt). I am specifying the column widths of my `longtable` in pts in order to get the exact spacing I need. Or is there a more elegant way to do it?  
Here's what I have:  
`\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}`  
`\begin{longtable}[l]{p{10pt}p{20pt}p{20pt}p{419.755pt}}`

Comment: you can try `ltxtable` package http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/carlisle/ltxtable.pdf